# Broadcast event to nested route in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have folowing routes

```
<script>
  routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
      children: [{
          path: 'nested1',
          name: 'nested1',
          component: Nested1,
        }, {
          path: 'nested2',
          name: 'nested2',
          component: Nested2,
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Here my `Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="toolbar-actions">
        <el-button :plain="true" type="info" @click="goBack" size="small" icon="arrow-left">Back</el-button>
        <el-button type="success" @click="onSubmit" size="small" icon="check">Submit</el-button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <el-row>
      <el-col :span="4">
        <div class="sidemenu-wrapper">
          <el-menu :router="true" default-active="0" class="sidemenu" ref="sidemenu">
            <el-menu-item index="0" :route="{name: 'nested1'}">nested 1</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="1" :route="{name: 'nested2'}">nested 2</el-menu-item>
        </div>
      </el-col>

      <el-col :span="20">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      // here I want to be able run certain method in 
      // child route
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

And `Nested1.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <el-row>
      <el-col :span="4">
        <el-from>
          <!-- inputs, selects, etc -->
        </el-from>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      // bla bla bla
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      // send data to backend 
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

I want to find out the way to excute Nested1's `submit` method by clicking Submit button in Home. Is it possible?

Comment: There's really not enough information here. It's unclear what you are even asking

Comment: At a guess, you could always use an event bus ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Answer (score -1):

In your `Home.vue` change this line:

```
<router-view :ref="routerView"></router-view>
```

And call this method to execute `submit` in `Nested1`:

```
this.$refs.routerView.submit()
```